# Windows 7 - OpenVPN - Use second network interface

Tags: windows, openvpn

is it possible to configure Windows 7 to connect to a OpenVPN Server using a different network interface.

My setup:
1. LAN -> public ip
2. LAN -> public ip
3. Tun -> private VPN

now i want that lan1 is used for normal surfing and lan2 is used for the tunnel.

Is this possible to configure?

Answer (score 3):

The VPN gateway is routed just like everything else. All you need is to add a route pointing to the VPN gateway, leading out the preferred NIC.

```
route add <VPN gateway IP> mask 255.255.255.255 <default gateway IP> metric 1 if <interface number>
```

The `<default gateway IP>` needs to be the local default gateway for the NIC in question, the `<interface number>` you can get with `route print`. You can omit the `if <interface number>` when the default gateway isn't reachable from the other NIC.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but does not work.
i use the vpn only for a samba share and want that the traffic is send via the second interface. is there a option to force openvpn using the second card?

Comment: Please try a `traceroute <VPN gateway IP>` to verify the routing is working. If it doesn't please post `route print` output and your network/IP address details (they don't have to be real).